# JQ: console error "(...).slideToggle(); is not function" My slideToggle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My slideToggle() doesn't work. Also, in the console is show an error that says ""(...).slideToggle() is not a function". I tried isolating the JQ reference from the other that I'm using, but still don't working. Help pls.

```
    $('.fa-bars').click(function(){
        $('.nav-2').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Here is my proyect: https://jsfiddle.net/s0f1r8wj/

Comment: Could you give the full message given by the console?

Comment: I see eight 404 error messages in console.

Comment: jQuery Slim does not include slideToggle. The jsfiddle is using slim

Comment: @Sarah Thanks Sarah! That was the problem ;).